# How to add properties file to java classpath using command-line?

Tags: java, spring

My current structure looks like

```
$ls
project.jar
propertiesFileA
propertiesFileB
```

The way I run my project, I do

```
java -jar project.jar MyClass
```

It's a `Spring` based project where `context.xml` resolves some of the properties from `propertiesFileA` and `propertiesFileB`

So I get error because Spring can not find these files. That means I need to add them to `classpath`.

I tried following with no success at all

```
java -classpath .:/project.jar MyClass

java -cp "project.jar:." MyClass

java -classpath .;project.jar MyClass
```

**Question**

How can I provide `propertiesFileA` and `propertiesFileB` on command-line to `MyClass`?

Comment: I think properties file outside the jar file can be accessed from jar if they are on same directory.

Comment: @Sarit, I agree with your comment, but the problem here is Spring. It needs to know the presence of these property files; and to be able to use them. If the property files were inside JAR then it would not be a problem.

Comment: Where does Spring look for these resources? Where is the relevant code and configuration? What's the exception you get?

Comment: Did you try PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer ?

Comment: How are your loading your property files in spring

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your question title, "How to add properties file to java classpath using command-line?", to be specific, you need to add to the class path the directory that contains your properties files.

For example, if your properties files are located at

- /path/to/your/properties/files/file1.properties
- /path/to/your/properties/files/file2.properties

Then what you need is to add their directory (/path/to/your/properties/files/, or /path/to/your/properties/files) to the class path, such as:

```
java -cp "/path/to/your/properties/files/:/path/to/your/project.jar:/path/to/3rdparty/jars/*" com.shn.ec.main.MyClass

java -cp "/path/to/your/properties/files:/path/to/your/project.jar:/path/to/3rdparty/jars/*" com.shn.ec.main.MyClass
```

Answer (score 0):

The following helped me

```
java -cp ".:project.jar:3rdparty/*" com.shn.ec.main.MyClass
```

I was missing `FQCN` when calling out class